# limit of positive concave function is concave

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, convex-analysis

Let $A\subsetneq \mathbb{R}^{n}$( A is compact). Consider $f:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{+}^{n}\cup\{0\}$ is continuous map. Suppose that for all $a\in A$ , $\alpha \mapsto f(\alpha)$ is concave positive function.

Let $\beta_{n} \in A$. We can show that if $f(\beta_{n})\rightarrow f(\beta)$, then $f(\beta)>0$.

Can one give an counter example for above question when concavcity drop?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $f(x) = x$ on $A=(0,1)$ shows that this is not true with $f({1 \over n}) \to 0$.

Comment: I modifed question. Can you give a counter example when concavcity drop?

Comment: I am sure you can modify the previous example to obtain a convex example.

Comment: But i assume A is compact.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is wrong. Here is a counterexample.

Let $A=(-1,1)$, $f(x) =\max(1- |x|,0)$, $\beta_n = 1 + \frac1n$. Then $\beta_n\to 1$, $f(\beta_n)\to0$.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know under which assumption the statment is true?

Comment: Compactness of $A$ should be sufficient. Then the minimum of $f$ on $A$ is positive.

Comment: Thanks. Let us assume A is compact. Do we still need to assume concavcity ?

Comment: No.....................